# How do I disable MySQL on Linux from starting on boot or statup?

Tags: mysql, mariadb, linux, ubuntu

After adding MySQL to Ubuntu, it automatically starts up on server boot. I would like it to not start up with the system.

How can I disable it and manually start it?

Answer (score 20, accepted):

[MariaDB use `systemd`](https://mariadb.com/kb/en/library/systemd/) as does [MySQL](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/using-systemd.html). To disable MySQL or MariaDB, from starting on bootup, run

```
systemctl list-unit-files '*mariadb*' '*mysql*'
```

If you see `mysql.service`, try disabling that one first.

```
sudo systemctl disable mysql
```

Now you can start and stop MySQL with

```
sudo systemctl stop mysql.service
sudo systemctl start mysql.service
```

Comment: You can always compile it from source and script the startup/shutdown. I like the fine-grained control this gives. I needed it for College where the only way I could run MySQL was to compile it and run it myself (no superuser privileges for me :-) )

Answer (score 8):

In Ubuntu 18.04, `sudo systemctl disable mysql` will prevent `mysql-server` from autostarting on boot.

For linux, there are 3 main init systems: `Systemd`, `Upstart` and `SysV`. Although nearly all Linux systems run on Systemd. The other two init systems might also co-exist in your system.

For `Systemd`, use command `sudo systemctl disable mysql`;
For `Upstart`, use `echo manual >> /etc/init/mysql.override`;
For `SysV`, run the following command `sudo update-rc.d mysql disable`

If you'd like to find which init system is running on your server, please read this [answer](https://unix.stackexchange.com/a/196183/340999).